# TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value in firebase-admin.initializeApp()

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

So I've working on this project for a while and never faced any such issue. In the last commit, I made some changes in the HTML files of the project and practically no major change in my app.js. But all of a sudden, I get the following error whenever I try to run the code locally:
[Error message from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPjad.png)

Here's what the code looks like:
[Screenshot of the code. Line#15 is initializeApp()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQQgF.png)

I have no idea what's happening here. Please help.

PS1. This is NOT a new project. I've been working on this for over a year and haven't faced this issue ever.

PS2. I tried reverting to old commits (even the very first commit for that matter) and still got the same issue (it used to work back then).

PS3. These are not environment related issues. I set up the project on a different machine afresh and got the same issue. Another Firebase project on my machine is surprisingly working just fine.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After breaking my head on it for hours, I finally realized that I was initializing firebase-admin just to access the cloud firestore which I can do just with firebase. So I replace the code wherever I was accessing cloud firestore through firebase-admin with one which allows me to access firestore through firebase and voila! It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not done any code change and even the first commit is not working for you, it seems to be an environmental issue.

The console error that you have attached shows that your code is using some libs present at **appdata/roaming**, try clearing it and re-downloading it. Also clear any local cache at IDE level or disk level.

Comment: I set it up afresh on a different laptop and faced the same issue. So environmental issues are pretty unlikely to be the reason. 

FYI, another firebase project on my machine works just fine on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put you credentials (apiKey, authDoamin, databaseURL etc) as an object to initializeApp() method

Should look like this:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "api-key",
  authDomain: "project-id.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://project-id.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "project-id",
  storageBucket: "project-id.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "sender-id",
  appId: "app-id",
  measurementId: "G-measurement-id",
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

For more details - follow the link
https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Comment: If I'm not wrong, this is how you initialize 'firebase'. I am facing an error when initializing 'firebase-admin'. Check the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQQgF.png

Comment: In this case
const firebase = require("firebase-admin");
Initialize you app first and then use the functions